# ¿Cómo instalar Flutter correctamente?

Tags: flutter, dart, powershell, sdk

recientemente descargué el SDK de Flutter, he tratado de ubicarlo según los tutoriales que he consultado para finalmente ejecutar flutter doctor  o flutter en Windows PowerShell, pero hasta ahora solo consigo este resultado:

```
PS C:\Users\zatia> flutter doctor
flutter : El término 'flutter' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa
ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta
es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ flutter doctor
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Agradecería sinceramente la experticia de alguien en Stack Overflow, supongo que tiene que ver con las rutas de acceso y las rutas configuradas en la variable de entorno, pero ni siquiera actualizando dichas variables puedo lograr que ejecute Flutter.

Comment: asegúrate que la variable de entorno PATH esté apuntando a la carpeta **bin** de donde pusiste los archivos de **flutter**, cuando guardes esa modificación reinicia la terminal que estés usando para que los cambios se actualicen

Comment: A mi forma de ver lo más fácil es descargarte Android Studio con esto todas tu variables de entorno van a estar correctamente configuradas. Despues agregas el plugin de `Fluter` y listo a su vez ya solo en tu editor de codigo favorito. Y ya con la experiencia podrías proceder a hacerlo por tu cuenta desde cero y ya manajar tus `PATH` lo importante es que empieces a desarrollar.

Comment: segun la documentacion: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/desktop

Answer (score 2):

@GordonGuitar

Recomendación para instalar desde Windows el método más fácil es

```
winget install Google.Flutter
```

[Nota](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/package-manager/winget/#install-winget): Actualmente, la herramienta de línea de comandos `winget` solo se admite en Windows 10 1709 (compilación 16299) o posterior. La herramienta winget no estará disponible hasta que haya iniciado sesión en Windows como usuario por primera vez, lo que desencadena Microsoft Store para registrar el Administrador de paquetes de Windows como parte de un proceso asincrónico. Si ha iniciado sesión recientemente como usuario por primera vez y encuentra que la herramienta winget aún no está disponible, puede abrir PowerShell y escribir el siguiente comando para solicitar este registro de winget: `Add-AppxPackage -RegisterByFamilyName -MainPackage Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe`.

Comment: puedes agregar la de choco tambien: _choco install flutter_

Comment: `puedes agregar la de choco tambien: choco install flutter`


Requiere la instalación del [choco installer](https://chocolatey.org/install) en Windows

Si no desea utilizar un instalador externo, el paquete gestor nativo de Windows es `winget`.

Answer (score -1):

la forma mas fácil es que bajes la carpeta de flutter como zip o con git y copies la ruta donde la guardaste en tus variables de entorno
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]